# Near duplicate worth making separate question?

Tags: discussion, questions

**Curriculum vitae** (often abbreviated CV) is a common Latin locution present in a high number of languages. Roughly, more than half the links in *other languages* in [curriculum vitae Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curriculum_vitae) go to articles with the same name in the respective languages, and there are other cases like [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebenslauf_(Bewerbung)), where even if the article has a different name, the locution is cited as an alternative.

A common doubt among people is what is the Latin plural for this locution.

There is [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/1570/how-to-form-the-plural-of-noun-plus-noun-in-possessive-case) that asks for a more general case, where CV is cited as an example in the question's body.

A google search on the [plural of curriculum vitae](https://www.google.com/search?q=plural%20of%20curriculum%20vitae&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) leads to other sites and gives the impression that both *curricula vitarum* and *curricula vitae* are correct. Latin.SE does not appear among the top results.

My proposal is that we **make a separate question explicitly about the plural of CV even if it is arguably a duplicate, for the sake of searchability**. So my meta question is: What do you think, should we?

Comment: [The question has now been asked at the site.](http://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2987/79)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, we should.

I think it would make sense to have a separate question about just *curriculum vitae* and its plural.
This is something people will want to know, and our site should give an answer without sidetracking to something more general.
Such a question with a good answer or two would bring positive visibility for our site.
I would not consider the questions duplicates, if the new one focuses on the popular issue of *curriculum vitae*.

Duplicate questions are welcome.
Questions marked as duplicate are not subject to automatic deletion like other closed questions.
They are kept because they are considered useful; they help users find what they need.
If a question is closed as duplicate and the asker is satisfied with the linked answer, the new question should not be deleted.
Even if the CV question you propose was considered duplicate (I would disagree!), it would be perfectly fine to post it.

I would like to see an answer comparing *curricula vitae*, *curriculum vitarum*, *curricula vitarum*, and maybe even other alternatives.